# Restore Jenkins backup from another filesystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops

I need to restore my jenkins configuration from a backup (AWS Snapshot). I have an EC2 instance that, following and update, lost the jenkins configuration. My first attempt was to restore the EC2 AMI to the point before the update, but still the jenkins configuration was missing.

We take a AWS snapshot nightly of jenkins. From this I created a volume and mounted it on to the EC2 box. I mounted it in to `/media/jenkins/` and saw that the jenkins data was there. It came in at 37Gb. I restinstalled Jenkins on the instance and tried to symlink `/var/lib/jenkins/` to `/media/jenkins/` However this caused `Too many levels of symbolic links`

It is jenkins_home which is 37GB. The EC2 instance where jenkins runs only has 17 GB free (it's a 40GB Box). Therefore I'm assuming that all the data in the backup was not originally on the box.

My question is do I need to copy the entire 37GB into /var/lib/jenkins/ which seems a brute force approach, or is there a more sensible way to restore jenkins.

Here is my empty jenkins configuration

```
[10:43][ip-10-0-33-8:/var/lib/jenkins[1]]$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct  4 12:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Oct  4 11:04 ..
```

and in the backup mount

```
[10:43][ip-10-0-33-8:/media/jenkins[1]]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 jenkins jenkins 4096 Oct  4 12:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Oct  4 10:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 40 jenkins jenkins 4096 Sep 29 16:12 jenkins_home
```

And inside jenkins_home

```
[10:26][ip-10-0-33-8:/media/jenkins/jenkins_home]$ ls -la
total 476
drwxr-xr-x  40 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 29 16:12 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Oct  4 12:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 28 14:35 .apex
-rw-------   1 jenkins jenkins  2948 Aug 17 10:27 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Feb  9  2017 .bower
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 cache
drwxr-xr-x   6 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jul 11 13:36 .cache
drwxr-xr-x   9 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jun 21 15:08 caches
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   252 Aug 16 16:47 com.chikli.hudson.plugin.naginator.NaginatorPublisher.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   120 Jan 29  2017 com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   337 Aug 16 16:47 com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugins.buildmonitor.BuildMonitorView.xml
drwxr-xr-x   6 jenkins jenkins  4096 Aug 17 10:25 .config
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins 14794 Sep 25 08:43 config.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     0 Jan 29  2017 Connection Activity monitoring to slaves.log
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  1155 Aug  7 15:29 credentials-configuration.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  4288 Jul 26 11:27 credentials.xml
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 docs
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     0 Jan 29  2017 Download metadata.log
drwxr-xr-x 258 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 fingerprints
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 29  2017 .fontconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   214 Aug 16 16:47 github-plugin-configuration.xml
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 29  2017 .groovy
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   808 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   159 Sep 25 08:42 hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   288 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.plugins.analysis.core.GlobalSettings.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  1521 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   322 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   370 May 15 16:04 hudson.plugins.git.GitTool.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   688 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   523 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.scm.CVSSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   388 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   145 May 15 16:04 hudson.tasks.Ant.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   626 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   571 May 15 16:04 hudson.tasks.Maven.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins    76 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.tasks.Shell.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   215 Aug 16 16:47 hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger.xml
-rw-------   1 jenkins jenkins  1680 Jan 29  2017 identity.key.enc
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 29  2017 .java
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 30  2017 .jenkins
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins    94 Jun 29 16:08 jenkins.CLI.xml
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 jenkins.diagnostics.ooom.OutOfOrderBuildMonitor
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     6 Jan 29  2017 jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     6 Jan 29  2017 jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   191 Aug 16 16:47 jenkins.metrics.api.MetricsAccessKey.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   159 Aug 16 16:47 jenkins.model.ArtifactManagerConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   138 Jan 29  2017 jenkins.model.DownloadSettings.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   236 Aug 16 16:47 jenkins.model.JenkinsLocationConfiguration.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   247 May 15 16:04 jenkins.mvn.GlobalMavenConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   457 May 15 16:04 jenkins.plugins.shiningpanda.tools.PythonInstallation.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   401 Aug 16 16:47 jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   310 Aug 16 16:47 jenkins.plugins.slack.webhook.GlobalConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   169 Jan 29  2017 jenkins.security.QueueItemAuthenticatorConfiguration.xml
drwxr-xr-x  87 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 14 11:52 jobs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 31  2017 .local
drwxr-xr-x   5 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 logs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 30  2017 .m2
drwxr-xr-x   5 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jul 14 14:31 .node-gyp
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   911 Sep 25 08:42 nodeMonitors.xml
drwxr-xr-x   5 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 30 07:49 nodes
drwxr-xr-x 938 jenkins jenkins 36864 Sep  4 13:57 .npm
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   241 Aug 16 16:47 org.codefirst.SimpleThemeDecorator.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   298 May 15 16:04 org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  1830 Sep 25 08:43 org.jenkinsci.plugins.ghprb.GhprbTrigger.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   255 May 15 16:04 org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitApacheTool.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   243 May 15 16:04 org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitTool.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   290 Aug 16 16:47 org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.config.GlobalConfig.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins    46 Sep 29 15:57 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.flow.FlowExecutionList.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   218 Aug 16 16:47 org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   367 Aug 16 16:47 org.jenkinsci.plugins.zap.ZAPBuilder.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   185 Aug 16 16:47 org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SSHBuildWrapper.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins  2630 Jan 29  2017 Out of order build detection.log
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins    46 Oct  1 00:35 .owner
drwxr-----   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 30  2017 .pki
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 14 14:45 .plotly
drwxr-xr-x 141 jenkins jenkins 20480 Sep  6 13:11 plugins
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Aug 11 16:52 .pylint.d
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Mar  3  2017 .python-eggs
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins 18064 Sep 25 08:42 queue.xml.bak
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 30  2017 .qws
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins   369 Jun 29 16:08 scriptApproval.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins    64 Jan 29  2017 secret.key
-rw-r--r--   1 jenkins jenkins     0 Jan 29  2017 secret.key.not-so-secret
drwx------   4 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jun 29 16:00 secrets
drwx------   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jul  3 14:51 .ssh
drwxrwxrwx 522 jenkins jenkins 20480 Sep 28 12:43 temp
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 test
drwxr-xr-x  16 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   3 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 tools
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 30 08:43 updates
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 userContent
drwxr-xr-x  77 jenkins jenkins  4096 Sep 18 14:07 users
-rw-------   1 jenkins jenkins   792 May 15 13:05 .viminfo
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Jan 28  2017 workflow-libs
drwxr-xr-x 108 jenkins jenkins 12288 Sep 25 01:06 workspace
drwxr-xr-x   2 jenkins jenkins  4096 Aug 16 16:55 .ZAP
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jenkins or AWS, and instead has to do with how your directory tree is structured. Unfortunately, you don't give any information about that, but I'd start with (1) the exact command that you used to do the symlink, with errors, _copied from the terminal_, and (2) `ls -al` of `/var/lib/jenkins` and `/media/jenkins`.

Comment: @kdgregory is turns out the issue with the symlink was solved by using full rather than relative paths. It still doesn't solve my problem as I need to do the initial fresh install of jenkins and then switch the `JENKINS_HOME` variable.

Comment: This has also nothing to do with DevOps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should copy all the 37 GB **this** time. but for the next try to understand why you have 37 GB of data. 
you can ignore the workspace folder it contain just temp files to build on the Master.

check if there are some problematic builds that has too many history and archive some files , maybe you can reduce the data.

another option is to start use the thin backup plugin - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/thinBackup it can backup all the configuration.

another backup option is to use the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin you can keep all configuration / history in Github or in any other source control.